# How can i develop a working shift formula that can have four posibilities of output

Tags: excel

I've been trying to develop a formula in excel to calculate the working shift by date and time, however I've got some troubles trying to reach a efficient one, some of them are the next ones:

-The validity of the formula in time is short.

-It has to be completely condicionated to wrok fine, demands a lot of computing, and it still has the validity short.

Now the bullets to define a formula are the next ones:

-The output must any of "1", "2", "3" and "4" with its conditions, the conditions are the next ones:

*1 is the shift where you work since 6:10 am to 6:10 pm, from sunday to tuesday and the wednesday you work one week and the other you dont. (For this year, the week number of the year must be pair for you to work in shift 1 the wednesday, the unpair one you dont)

*2 is the shift where you work since 6:10 am to 6:10 pm, from thursday to saturday and the wednesyou alternate the day with shift 1, example shift 1 worked one week the wednesday then you work the next one the wednesday.

*3 is the shift where you work since 6:10 pm to 6:10 am, from sunday to tuesday and the wednesday you work one week and the other you dont.

*4 is the shift where you work since 6:10 pm to 6:10 am, from thursday to saturday and the wednesyou alternate the day with shift 3, example shift 3 worked one week the wednesday then you work the next one the wednesday.

I've tried conditioning and it works but it has the two points I explain in the question. conditioning you get it to work like 3 years.
I'm looking for a synthesized way to calculate it with its two variables (Date and time) in a way really complete and maybe analyze the way to do it.

The formula is the next one (in cell F14 I've date and time, it can be separated there's no problem with that) :
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(F14)<=3,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(F14,5),6))>6.16666666/24,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(F14,5),6))<18.16666666/24),"T1",IF(AND(WEEKDAY(F14)>=5,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(F14,5),6))>6.16666666/24,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(F14,5),6))<18.16666666/24),"T2",IF(AND(WEEKDAY(F14)=4,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(F14,5),6))>6.16666666/24,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(F14,5),6))<18.16666666/24,VALUE(RIGHT(YEAR(F14)/2,2))=0.5,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(WEEKNUM(F14)/2,2),2))<>0.5),"T1",IF(AND(WEEKDAY(F14)=4,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(F14,5),6))>6.16666666/24,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(F14,5),6))<18.16666666/24,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(WEEKNUM(F14)/2,2),2))=0.5),"T2",IF(AND(WEEKDAY(F14)=1,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(F14,5),6))<6.16666666/24),"T4",IF(AND(WEEKDAY(F14)<=4,VALUE(RIGHT(ROUND(F14,5),6))<6.16666666/24),"T3","N"))))))

Comment: I got confused by all the words and could not find any examples to follow.  I am EntirelyClueless.

Comment: Yeah my apologies,  i tried to set the bullets but seems that it cannot be done the way i did it. The important part that i need to develop is the conditions to be successfully achieved is the one that I specify the way the outputs must be 1, 2,3 and 4.

Comment: I want to help but I don't understand what you're trying to do.  It will help me understand if you can provide an example that I can follow.  A good start would be one picture with your source data and another picture of the result you are trying to get.

Comment: thank you, an example could be the next one: You got to fill the week with working shifts so you make 4 of them, you numbered them 1, 2, 3 and 4. Now you need to know of some data which shift generate it with the variables time and date.

Comment: 1 and 3 work since sunday to tuesday without change, 1 at day and 3 at night. 2 and 4 work since thursday to saturday without change, 2 at day and 4 at night. The wednesday alternates between 1 and 3 and 2 and 4, example for this year we are 7/7/19 the week number of this day is a pair number so shift 1 and 3 work wednesday, but the next week the week number will be an unpair so shift 2 and 4 work wednesday. IDK if it is still confusing.

Comment: I know how to conditionate it in excel, but there's still a variable about years periodicity that i can't do so much with, this makes the formula to expire or be useful just some years. I wonder if there's another way to reach a better solution than conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations.  I believe I understand your objective.  You say you have a formula that works sometimes but not always, can you include it in an update to your question?

Comment: It's too long i edited the post, there it is, those are raw conditions of time and date.

Comment: I have two different methods calculating the same result for 1,000 rows.  I'll condense the formula and present both in the answer.

Comment: I'm looking forward to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have to be a little honest. I had every intent to walk through your formula, figure out why we got different results, and explain what happened.  But I couldn't stay focused and my mind started drifting towards more pleasant things like responding to HOA letters,  paying taxes, and solving Pi.  So I didn't do it....  Moving on!

I believe I understood what you needed.  There are four shifts in total, with two shifts per day.  Shifts 1 and 3 work Sunday through Tuesday, 1 starts at 06:10 and is relieved at 18:10 when shift 3 starts.  It is similar for Shifts 2 and 4, their days are Thursday through Saturday and they have the same hours.  Wednesdays alternate between the two groups with 1 and 3 taking Wednesday when the week number is wholly divisible by two.  Shifts 2 and 4 take the alternate Wednesday.

You can see my test data in the image below and I believe you'll find the results align with my explanation.  You'll note there is a data column to the left of the date and another to the right.  This is because I tested two different methods.  The results align so I have high confidence in the quality of my work and I remain hopeful that put you in the right direction.

The column to the left of the dates uses a very short formula:

`=CoveringShift(B1)`

And the column to the right of the dates uses a much longer formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(B1)<>4,IF(WEEKDAY(B1)<=3,IF(AND(TIME(HOUR(B1),MINUTE(B1),0)>=TIME(6,10,0),TIME(HOUR(B1),MINUTE(B1),0)<TIME(18,10,0)),1,3),IF(AND(TIME(HOUR(B1),MINUTE(B1),0)>=TIME(6,10,0),TIME(HOUR(B1),MINUTE(B1),0)<TIME(18,10,0)),2,4)),IF(ISEVEN(WEEKNUM(B1)),IF(AND(TIME(HOUR(B1),MINUTE(B1),0)>=TIME(6,10,0),TIME(HOUR(B1),MINUTE(B1),0)<TIME(18,10,0)),1,3),IF(AND(TIME(HOUR(B1),MINUTE(B1),0)>=TIME(6,10,0),TIME(HOUR(B1),MINUTE(B1),0)<TIME(18,10,0)),2,4)))
```

[image: Test Date]

Ok, ok, you caught me.  I used VBA to create a User Define Function.  This is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CoveringShift(TimeQuery As Date) As Single
    Dim AM As Date
    Dim PM As Date
    Dim Shifts As String
    Dim iVal As Integer
    AM = TimeSerial(6, 10, 0)
    PM = TimeSerial(18, 10, 0)
    iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(TimeQuery)
    Select Case Weekday(TimeQuery, vbSunday)
        Case 1 To 3
            Shifts = "1,3"
        Case 5 To 7
            Shifts = "2,4"
        Case 4
            If iVal / 2 - Int(iVal / 2) = 0 Then
                Shifts = "1,3"
            Else
                Shifts = "2,4"
            End If
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Something bad happened"
    End Select
    Select Case TimeValue(TimeQuery)
        Case Is < AM
            Shifts = Right(Shifts, 1)
        Case AM To DateAdd("s", -1, PM)
            Shifts = Left(Shifts, 1)
        Case Is >= PM
            Shifts = Right(Shifts, 1)
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Something bad happened"
    End Select
    CoveringShift = CSng(Shifts)
End Function
```

Personally, I prefer the cleanliness and readability of the UDF; but sometimes VBA's baggage isn't worth carrying.

I hope this helped in some way!

Comment: WOW Thank you, let me review it and i'll for sure answer you, to be honest i never expected some kind of development like this.

Comment: Pretty nice, seems like it works i can only add that you can't prevent from the periodicity of years changes the week number from pair to impair. This means that you will need to correct the formula through time, it's kind of difficult to correct that.

Comment: I don't follow....  I think you are saying that weeks change from wholly divisible by two and not wholly divisible by two over many years but  I don't see how that's possible.  It doesn't matter if it's 100 years ago or 100 years in the future, week #22 will always be week #22 and wholly divisible by 2.  It is not always guaranteed to be in the same month but I don't believe that was a requirement.  If you help me understand the problem  then I will try to find a solution.

Comment: What I mean is that conditionating the formula like that you get the results, but periodically you'll need to correct the condition of pair week shift 1 and impair week shift 2 and swap it up.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that means you see a shift work Wednesday on the final week of the year and the same shift work Wednesday on the first week of the year.  That's the only way that can happen and that's impossible with formula I gave you because the only way that can happen is if there are not 52 weeks in the ending year... And this is where I learned you are from somewhere interesting because I just looked it up and some countries can have 53 weeks depending on several factors.  I can easily work it into the formula but it is likely to more than double the length.  Will update.

Comment: It is my turn to say "WOW".  This afternoon has been a learning experience for me!  I can see why you struggled with a solution that doesn't require an adjustment, it is more difficult than I thought it would be.  I believe I'm closing in on it on the VBA side, not quite there yet.  Not sure how to tackle it with a formula.  This is a fun challenge.  You may not hear back from me for a day or two but I will keep working on it.

Comment: Haha, thank you yeah It's quite hard to get to know what actually is the point at first sight, and solving it even harder, thank you for trying you have thaught me a lot that's for sure too.

Comment: That's why i wasn't specifying that you must solve it on VBA or formula or other program, the problem is not the way you develop the formula is the integrity of its own. It's a mathematics problem, only logic can solve it and I've been thinking about it a lot of time without concluding anything yet.

Comment: Hi ! I've comeback to tell you the answer @profoundlyoblivious! You must segment the n number divided by 7 to get the binary condition for the change onto the weekly change and you will be able to develop an exact formula!

Comment: Thank you by for help, and if you're interested in the design of the formula we can discuss it aswel!